# C How to pass arguments using cmd and use it in execvp

Tags: c

I'm trying to send using the command line to send arguments to a C File and after that use it as arguments of a execvp function

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){
    pid_t p;

    char * vec [] = {*argv, (char*)NULL};

    for(i = 0; i < argc ; i++){ 
        p = fork(); 

        if(p > 0 ){
            //Fork validations
        }else{
            execvp(vec[0], vec);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the shell i'm trying to use   **./executable 3 ls ps who**

After that the programm freezes and dont show the commands!

Any help?

Comment: What happens with your current solution?

Comment: the programm freezes and dont show the commands

Comment: Did you try firing up gdb?

Comment: A few issues I can see: your use of `vec` seems somewhat confusing, what is it supposed to be? `execvp(vec[0], vec);` doesn't really make any sense, and also `execvp` seems to require the filename of the executable, not just the command name. Maybe look at `system` instead?

Comment: but since when i execute the commands the first things is the name of executable... And i need to use execvp to resolve this problem

Comment: @DanielGibbs it makes sense (the first argument needs to be the command name as well), and `exec*p*` functions require command name only; they will look it up in PATH.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Whoops, you're right; I didn't read far down enough on the man page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simple. Instead of executing commands from your arguments, your definition

```
char *vec[] = {*argv, (char*)NULL};
```

or easier to understand,

```
char *vec[] = {argv[0], (char*)NULL};
```

and the fact that you never change this `vec`, means that you're re-executing command whose name is in `argv[0]`... and it is the name of **your executable** so your code keeps executing itself and forking itself all the time, creating a **fork bomb**.

---

What you wanted to do is to execute commands from arguments. I am not sure what the `3` does in arguments, but I presume you want to execute the rest from there as commands:

```
char *vec[] = {0, 0};
// only process arguments starting from 2 (a.k.a ls in your example)
for(i = 2; i < argc ; i++){ 
    vec[0] = argv[i];
    if (!fork()) {
        execvp(vec[0], vec);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Of course it is not necessary to use `execvp` and `vec` if you're not passing variable number of arguments; `execlp` will work just fine:

```
for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
    if (!fork()) {
        execlp(argv[i], argv[i], (char*)0);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just in luck I currently have an assigment due on the same subject.

1) Why are you using

> char * vec [] = {*argv, (char*)NULL};

Use argv directly that's the whole point plus it will make your code MUCH more clearer.

I recommend making a generic function which will separate your input in options and parameters and use a callback making it much more flexible but that's up to you.
Something like this

```
typedef int (*pCallback) (char *, char*, void *);
int parseCmdLine(int argc, char *argv[], pCallback p, void
*userData); 
int parseCallback(char *key, char *value, void *userData);
```

Could you post the prototypes to your functions so that it's clearer what you want to do.

Plus you're also forgetting the declaration of i. I would recommend using something clearer like argv_counter:

> int argv_counter;

It's not really clear what you're trying to do post a more complete code. Here's what I would fix of what I've seen plus I don't see the point in 
Why not just pass argv or argv[0], no point in passing both.

> execvp(argv[0], argv);

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){
    pid_t p;
    int argv_counter;
    char * vec [] = {*argv, (char*)NULL};

    for(argv_counter = 0; argv_counter < argc ; argv_counter++){ 
        p = fork(); 

        if(p > 0 ){
            //Fork validations
        }
        else{
            execvp(argv[0], argv);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```